# Proposition: Let $m\in \mathbb N$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$. If $m·n\in \mathbb N$, then $n\in \mathbb N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof:

$m·n\in \mathbb N$

Suppose BWOC $n\notin \mathbb N$.

Then $n=0$, or $-n\in \mathbb N$.

Case 1: $n = 0$

$m·n\in \mathbb N$ and $m·0\in \mathbb N$

$0\in \mathbb N$. This is a false statement.

Case 2: $-n\in \mathbb N$

I don't know how to prove case 2 so that there will be a false statement.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For any integer $x$, if $x>0$ and $y>0$, then $xy>0$ also holds- you can write $xy$ as $x+x(y-1)$- now try using induction to show that $xy$ is always $>0$ (assume $x(y-1)>0$ and show what happens if $xy<0$)

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't gotten to induction proofs yet, so my professor won't accept it. Is there another way to prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use two of the axioms you mentioned being given- if $x$ and $y$ are natural, then so is $xy$ & either $x$ is natural, $x$ is $0$, or $-x$ is natural (for any integer $x$).

These are enough to tackle your case $2$, for if $-n$ is natural, then (by the first axiom I wrote above), $m(-n)$ must be natural so $-(mn)$ must be natural. But, $mn$ is natural (by assumption) which contradicts the second axiom. So $-n$ can't be natural. Since you've already ruled out $n=0$, by the second axiom again $n$ is natural.

(this is assuming you've proved the consistency of the axioms)

Answer (score 0):

Integer $n$ is natural whenever $n>0$. If $m > 0$ and $mn > 0$, then of course, $n > 0$.

Comment: I am not allowed to state this although it is obvious.

Comment: I have to use the axiom of natural numbers to prove it.

Comment: But how you define integers then? I learnt that $\mathbb Z$ are $N\times N$ divided by equivalence relation $(a, b) R (c, d) \Leftrightarrow a - c = b - d$. How are you using this definition here?

Comment: In my class, we defined integers to be members of a set equipped with binary operations addition, and multiplication.

Comment: The axiom I was given about Natural Numbers is 1) if m,n are natural numbers, then m+n is a natural number. 2) Same applies for multiplication. 3) 0 is not a natural number. 4) For every integer m, we have m is a natural number, m=0, or -m is a natural number.